# iOS Core Bluetooth scan issue, can't find target BT device

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth

With Core Bluetooth 4.0, Apple told us that all devices support BT 4.0 can inter-connect with iOS devices, but my experiments results are below:

1. Inter-connect between all iOS devices work well.
2. Choose 3 device with BT enable, iPhone 5 (iOS 7.1), Samsung Galaxy (Android 4.4), HTC One  (Android 4.4).

   a) Both Android devices scan can find iPhone 5.

   b) In settings page, iPhone 5 scan can find HTC One, but not Samsung Galaxy.

   c) Based on Apple Core Bluetooth library, my app scan but can't find any Android devices, but works well with Android devices.

Not sure how does iOS BT work? Can't scan dues to any confidential on Apple side?

Any idea or discussion will be appreciated, thanks in advance .

Comment: Which device is the peripheral role and which is the central?  Is your peripheral advertising the same service UUID that your central is scanning for?

Comment: Android device is peripheral and iPhone is central.

Comment: You can use the free light blue app from the App Store to scan for ble peripherals - that will at least let you see if your android code is advertising correctly

Comment: Good idea, LightBlue is a nice utility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some devices can't be found by BT scanning in settings page, but using CoreBlueTooth library is OK.